# sp unit seems different when applying from code and from xml

Tags: java, android, xml

Probably I will find a workaround for this issue myself, but I would like to know the reason of this phenomenon : 
When I set the font size of a view from xml

```
android:textSize="16sp"
```

and from code this way :

```
myTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
```

In both cases, i set the text value to 16sp but when I run it the two TextViews sizes are looking totally different! Is this java code wrong? Do I miss something?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're converting it twice...  setTextSize already doe it for you, so you don't have to applyDimension again.  Just use this:

```
myTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
```